# Small signal probe

Tags: oscilloscope, probe

I like to buy 2 good probes to measure small signals (<20mV). I use a cheap Chinese scope (Rigol 100Mhz).

What should I pay attention in terms of specs of the probes? My signals are not very fast (<10Mhz) but I need amplitude accuracy and low noise injection from these probes. Any recommendation where to go to buy such probes? (I have bought several low end probes from Dealextreme and they are gone <2months)

Thx

Answer (score 7):

> but I need amplitude accuracy

Oscopes are rarely more than 1% accurate in voltage.

I'd look for used name-brand probes (Tektronix, Agilent, LeCroy)

> I like to buy 2 good probes to measure small signals (<20mV).

This is a good application of a differential probe amplifier -- but they're usually not cheap.